# WCF web service call time out

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, wsdl

I am consuming a web service from a url.  When I test using SoapUI, I get the response immediately (See image below) and that the request data I sent out made it through to the other end.

So in my C# application I did the same thing, I consumed the web service wsdl and auto generated the proxy class.  I create a request based on that proxy class with the exact same request data I used in SoapUI and sent out.  I confirmed that at the other end they received my data successfully and no error is shown.

However, I never receive any ID back and after a while I would get this exception:

> Error The HTTP request to 'http://someURLWebservice.com/WSoperation' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:00:59.9470000. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

Am I missing something here? I downloaded the WSDL and generated the mock service with SoapUI and if I make a call to that mock web service locally, I would get it right away.the ID back right away.

Here is my code:

```
 string serverURL = Settings.Default.ExtensionServiceURL;

 //Get Proxy class client
 ext.ExtWSPortTypeClient client = new ext.ExtWSPortTypeClient();
 EndpointAddress addr = new EndpointAddress(serverURL);

 try
   {
      client.Endpoint.Address = addr;
      Uri site = new Uri(serverURL);
      client.Endpoint.ListenUri = site;
      ExtensionData eData = new ExtensionData();
      client.ChannelFactory.CreateChannel();

      Console.WriteLine("Sending Locator Event Request to Web Service");
      ext.locatorEventResponse1 resp = await client.locatorEventAsync(eData.GenerateLocatorEventRequest(ev));
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Error " + ex.Message);
   }
   finally
   {
       if (client != null)
       {
          ((ICommunicationObject)client).Close();
       }
   }
```

[image]

Comment: anybody? :(  ... I tried this same code to test out a web service at http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL and I got the response  with my application right away.

Comment: how are your settings on the server side?

Comment: that's the hard part, i'm writing this for integration so I don't really have any idea to be honest.  However, if you can point out things I should check with them then that will be helpful also.

Comment: Are you sure you call the exact same method with SoapUI?
Can't you call a non-async method on this webservice from c# code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I ended up configure Fiddler2 to sniff my SoapUI request and compare it against my application request.  In the the Application request header I saw the following:

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Host: engage.ext-inc.com
Content-Length: 1036
**Expect: 100-continue**
```

That Expect:100-continue is not in the SoapUI request which successfully sent out and got the response.  With this in mind I took the SoapUI request in Fiddler and compose a new one base on it...except I put in Expect:100-continue and guess what, I received no response.

Upon reading about it I came across this [link](http://alihamdar.com/2010/06/19/expect-100-continue/)

And voila, upon putting ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false; into my code prior making the web service call I get the response back right away.

Answer (score 3):

In a similar situation, I would start with the following:

Test with the WCF Client and capture the trace file:

- Configure WCF Tracing for the client
  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Send the message via your WCF Client Application
- Let the call timeout and save the trace log data

Test with the soapUI client and capture the Http Log

- Clear the soapUI http log (one of the tabs along the bottom)
- Send the message via the soapUI test request
- Save the Http Log

Once you have the trace information for both clients, you should be able to compare the transactions and hopefully determine the source of the issue.  In particular, I would suggest confirming the service addresses on both sides and then comparing the SOAP envelope to make sure the WCF bindings are set consistently with the soapUI settings.

In addition, you could also use Fiddler to view the web service communications.  The following SO post provides good reference links.  [Fiddler and Monitoring Web Service Traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223324/fiddler-and-monitoring-web-service-traffic)

Hope this helps.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Check the message quota settings, it might be that your service is sending more than what is configured